# Preselected 'all' by default in android.Intent gallery with multiple selection

Tags: android, android-intent

please help

how can i do preselection all for user in a native android gallery ?

here is a code

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, multiple);
            galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Pick an image");
            activity.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

its working fine, but initial stage 0 files are selected

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no means of pre-selecting anything when using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, let alone pre-selecting *everything*.

Also note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not tied to a gallery app, and there is no single "native Android gallery" app across the ~10,000 Android device models.

Comment: is it possible to do programmatic selection  after user will choose path in intent ?..  thx

Comment: @ShamilSungatullin: No, sorry.